Convexity of the Airy's function on $[0, +\infty[$
I am studying some qualitative properties about the Airy's function but I am blocked on some problems.
Let $f$ be the unique solution of the differential equation :
$$ y'' = x y \quad (\mathrm{E})$$
with initial conditions $y(0) > 0$ and $y'(0) < 0$. I'd like to prove (maybe without using the integral expression of the Airy's function and with simple arguments) that $f$ is convex on $[0,+\infty[$ and that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) = 0.$
From the differential equation $(E)$, it is clear that on the interval $[0,+\infty[$ the convexity of $f$ is equivalent to the non negativity of $f$. Since $f(0) > 0$, we have $f''(x) \geqslant 0$ at least on a small neighborhood of $0^+$ but I don't manage to go further. Would you have any ideas ? Many thanks !
